# Recursive definition of arithmetic operators: How to memoize / cache?

Tags: python, recursion

All arithmetic operators are based on the fact that all natural number do have a successor. For educational purposes I implemented this idea as Python functions:

```
# recursive definition of arithmetic operators

a = 2
b = 3  # larger numbers won't work: RecursionError


def successor(n):
    """ returns n + 1. All other functions use successor recursively """
    return n + 1


def sum(n, m):
    """ sum a + b """
    if m == 0:
        return n
    if m == 1:
        return successor(n)
    else:
        return successor(sum(n, m - 1))

print(f"sum({a}, {b}) = {sum(a,b)}")


def product(n, m):
    """ multiplication n*m"""
    if m == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1:
        return sum(n, 0)
    else:
        return sum(product(n, m - 1), n)

print(f"product({a}, {b}) = {product(a, b)}")


def power(n, m):
    """ power n**m"""
    
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    elif m == 1:
        return product(n, 1)
    else:
        return product(power(n, m - 1), n)

print(f"power({a}, {b}) = {power(a, b)}")


def up_arrow_2(n, m):
    """ up_arrow operator 2nd degree: n**(n**( ....) m times """
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    elif m == 1:
        return power(n, 1)
    else:
        return power(up_arrow_2(n, m - 1), n)

print(f"up_arrow_2({a}, {b}) = {up_arrow_2(a, b)}")


def up_arrow_3(n, m):
    """ up_arrow operator 3rd degree"""
    if m == 0:
        return 1
    elif m == 1:
        return up_arrow_2(n, 1)
    else:
        return up_arrow_2(up_arrow_3(n, m - 1), n)

print(f"up_arrow_3({a}, {b}) = {up_arrow_3(a, b)}")
```

This works nicely for number up to `a=2` and `b=3` and then a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` happens when calculating `up_arrow_3(2, 4)` (and it's quite obvious why).

If I insert the line `return n**m` as the first line inside the `power` function, then much larger numbers can be calculated. Therefore, caching intermediate results seems to be a promising solution.

In order to extend to larger numbers, I tried memoizing using a decorator class such as

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args not in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.fn(*args)
        return self.memo[args]
```

and decorate the functions - without success.

I am looking for an idea how to write another decorator that does the required caching and allows for larger input numbers a, b.

**Edit:** Here is the solution worked out by @Urmzd using trampoline:

```
# recursive definition of arithmetic operators
from typing import Callable

a = 2
b = 3 

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}

    def memoize_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        str_args = f"{args}{kwargs}"
        return cache.get(str_args, func(*args, **kwargs))

    return memoize_inner

def trampoline(fn):
    def trampoline_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        fns = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        while(isinstance(fns, Callable)):
            fns = fns()

        return fns

    return trampoline_inner

def successor(n):
    """ returns n + 1. All other functions use successor recursively """
    return n + 1


@memoize
@trampoline
def _sum(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ sum a + b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 0 else lambda: successor(_sum(n, m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x)))

 
@memoize
@trampoline
def product(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ a*b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 1 else lambda: _sum(product(n, m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x)), n)

@memoize
@trampoline
def power(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ a*b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 1 else lambda: product(power(n, m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x)), n)

@memoize
@trampoline
def ua2(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ a*b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 1 else lambda: power(ua2(n, m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x)), n)

@memoize
@trampoline
def ua3(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ a*b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 1 else lambda: ua2(ua3(n, m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x)), n)


print(f"sum({a}, {b}) = {_sum(a,b)}")
print(f"product({a}, {b}) = {product(a,b)}")
print(f"power({a}, {b}) = {power(a,b)}")
print(f"ua2({a}, {b}) = {ua2(a,b)}")
print(f"ua3({a}, {b}) = {ua3(a,b)}")
```

Comment: Without caching, you can greatly increase the range of values `power` will work with by using repeated squaring, rather than simply iterating multiplication. (`power(a, b) == (b*power(a, b-1)) if b % 2 else (x := power(a, b//2))*x`).

Comment: +1 to chepner's suggestion. But also, have you tried https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache for the memoizing?

Comment: The idea is not to define power recursively on its own, but recurse all operators to `successor`

Comment: @HemanGandhi: I tried `functools.lru_cache()` and it did not improve the situation.

Comment: Memoization doesn't eliminate recursion or avoid the recursion-depth limitation. It just remembers prior answers and avoids unneeded recomputation. It optimizes away the guts of the calculation but does not alter the number of recursive calls. Partial workarounds for problems like this can be found in things like continuations, trampolines, etc. One reference: https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/on-recursion-continuations-and-trampolines/

Comment: @FMc: Excellent article, thanks!

Comment: Note that python has a builtin function called `sum`. It is strongly recommended **not** to shadow the names of builtins. Shadowing builtins can have unintended consequences.

Comment: You are also already using something other than `successor`, namely subtraction.

Comment: What you really want is dynamic programming. Just memoization still requires you recurse all the way to zero before any return value can be stored. Dynamic programming calculates the recursive calls from the bottom up.

Comment: @chepner you are right there is `m-1`, the predecessor, not yet full substraction. A full implementation would also define predecessor, substraction, division and so on. It is only the positive side of the story, but good enough to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will fix your issue.

```py
def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    def memoize_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        str_args = f"{args}{kwargs}"
        return cache.get(str_args, func(*args, **kwargs))

    return memoize_inner
```

Part of the reason why your code doesn't work is due to lack of optimality. But that's an entirely different issue, and can be resolve in various ways. If you want the memorization to work, you have to memorize all of your functions. This ensures that at each level, redundant computation is potentially reduced.

-- Edit

As mentioned earlier, your code is sub-optimal. Part of this due to a lack of recursion-optimization (tail-recursion using continuations, and stack optimization using thunks and trampolines).

So lets try fixing your code one step at a time (recursion-optimization has a greater overhead, so using the minimal amount of work should be attempted).

First, lets modify the `sum` function to make it tail-recursive (no-continuations needed):

```py
@memoize
def sum(n, m):
    """ sum a + b """
    return n if m == 0 else sum(successor(n), m-1))
```

Or if you really wanted to use continuations for whatever reason.

```py
@memoize
def sum(n, m, cont=lambda x: x):
    """ sum a + b """
    return cont(n) if m == 0 else sum(successor(n), m-1)
```

Then, we could make use of `thunks` by adding empty lambda functions for `lazy-evaluation`:

```py
@memoize
def sum(n, m, cont=lambda x: x):
    """ sum a + b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 0 else lambda: sum(successor(n), m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x))
```

And `trampolines` using the following util function which begins the recursion:

```py
from typing import Callable

def trampoline(fn):
    while(isinstance(fn, Callable)):
        fn = fn()
    
    return fn
```

If we wanted to invoke the function, we could do the following:

```
trampoline(sum(a,b))
```

However, if we want to implicitly invocate the thunks, we can make a trampoline decorator

```
def trampoline(fn):
    def trampoline_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        fns = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        while(isinstance(fns, Callable)):
            fns = fns()

        return fns

    return trampoline_inner
```

With this, you should have all the tools to fix the remaining functions and prevent recursion-depth-errors.

The full solution:

```py
from typing import Callable

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}

    def memoize_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        str_args = f"{args}{kwargs}"
        return cache.get(str_args, func(*args, **kwargs))

    return memoize_inner

def trampoline(fn):
    def trampoline_inner(*args, **kwargs):
        fns = fn(*args, **kwargs)

        while(isinstance(fns, Callable)):
            fns = fns()

        return fns

    return trampoline_inner

def successor(n):
    """ returns n + 1. All other functions use successor recursively """
    return n + 1


@memoize
@trampoline
def sum(n, m, cont=lambda x:x):
    """ sum a + b """
    return lambda: cont(n) if m == 0 else lambda: sum(successor(n), m-1, lambda x: lambda: cont(x))


print(f"sum({a}, {b}) = {sum(a,b)}")
```

Comment: Thanks, does not work for `a=2`and `b=4` ...
It's not about optimal code but demonstration of the fact that all arithmetic operators are based on seccession.

Comment: I see the problem, will optimize now and send full solution in a second.

Comment: @Nechoj hopefully the update helps you get in the right direction

Comment: @Nechoj The problem might be the lack of import. Post fixed, let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still, I have some questions. The version with continuations does not involve the successor anymore. Terefore, I cannot build the chain down to successor, right?

Comment: What do you mean `chain down` @Nechoj?

Comment: If I do this for `product`, in the recursion it shall call `sum` because `a*b = a + a+ ... a` b times. Same for sum: `a + b = a +1 +1 ... +1` = b times successor. See my original implementation. That means, at the end the highest operation uses recursion down until successor is called. It is not about implementing operators recursively *on its own* but building on top of the lower grade operations. The logic is along how the operators are being defined.

Comment: @Nechoj updated my answer (you could have alternatively just map a wrapper function, which you could invoke).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is the solution. I am stil struggling with defining product using sum inside, but this is a matter of time until I will get it ;-)